# Using CSS within javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load css from javascript. I have a little icon I need styles for that my users display on their site through my script tag like `<script src="mywebiste.com/api.js"></script`

Rather than doing inline styles like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML +=
'<div style="position:absolute;width:10%;height:10%;opacity:0.3;
             z-index:100;background:#000;">
</div>';
```

How can I load css styles from javascript? How do widgets like intercom.com do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the `div` inside `body`, You can use jQuery `css()`

```
$("body > div").css({
  "position": "absolute",
   "width": "10%",
   "height": "10%",
   "opacity" : "0.3",
   "z-index":"100",
   "background":"#000"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "path-to-your-css-file";
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.media = "screen,print";

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
</script>
```

Create the `<link>` element in javascript with `var link = document.createElement("link");`

Then add the necessary html attributes.

Finally append it to the `<head>` section:

`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);`